# How to run a class in a button in java swing application

Tags: java, sockets, desktop-application

I am a beginner in java coding. I want to create a files transfer through wifi application using java swing desktop application. I have seen some codes online for transferring the files. I have created a java swing application. But I am not getting how to insert the code in the send button which runs the main(File Sharing) code. So there are three classes Filevent, Server, Client in the code. The codes are given below.
so how to run the three classes when I clicked the send button?
And also suggest some easy codes to create a desktop application to share files through wifi.

### `FileEvent`

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class FileEvent implements Serializable {

    public FileEvent() {
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String destinationDirectory;
    private String sourceDirectory;
    private String filename;
    private long fileSize;
    private byte[] fileData;
    private String status;

    public String getDestinationDirectory() {
        return destinationDirectory;
    }

    public void setDestinationDirectory(String destinationDirectory) {
        this.destinationDirectory = destinationDirectory;
    }

    public String getSourceDirectory() {
        return sourceDirectory;
    }

    public void setSourceDirectory(String sourceDirectory) {
        this.sourceDirectory = sourceDirectory;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public void setFileSize(long fileSize) {
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public byte[] getFileData() {
        return fileData;
    }

    public void setFileData(byte[] fileData) {
        this.fileData = fileData;
    }
}
```

### `ServertClass`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    private FileEvent fileEvent;
    private File dstFile = null;
    private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    public Server() {
    }

    /**
     * Accepts socket connection
     */
    public void doConnect() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4445);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reading the FileEvent object and copying the file to disk.
     */
    public void downloadFile() {
        try {
            fileEvent = (FileEvent) inputStream.readObject();
            if (fileEvent.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Error")) {
                System.out.println("Error occurred ..So exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            String outputFile = fileEvent.getDestinationDirectory() + fileEvent.getFilename();
            if (!new File(fileEvent.getDestinationDirectory()).exists()) {
                new File(fileEvent.getDestinationDirectory()).mkdirs();
            }
            dstFile = new File(outputFile);
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
            fileOutputStream.write(fileEvent.getFileData());
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Output file : " + outputFile + " is successfully saved ");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.exit(0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.doConnect();
        server.downloadFile();
    }
}
```

### `ClientClass`

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
    private boolean isConnected = false;
    private final String sourceFilePath = "E:/temp/songs/song1.mp3";
    private FileEvent fileEvent = null;
    private final String destinationPath = "C:/tmp/downloads/";

    public Client() {
    }

    /**
     * Connect with server code running in local host or in any other host
     */
    public void connect() {
        while (!isConnected) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("localHost", 4445);
                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                isConnected = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sending FileEvent object.
     */
    public void sendFile() {
        fileEvent = new FileEvent();
        String fileName = sourceFilePath.substring(sourceFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, sourceFilePath.length());
        String path = sourceFilePath.substring(0, sourceFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        fileEvent.setDestinationDirectory(destinationPath);
        fileEvent.setFilename(fileName);
        fileEvent.setSourceDirectory(sourceFilePath);
        File file = new File(sourceFilePath);
        if (file.isFile()) {
            try {
                DataInputStream diStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                long len = (int) file.length();
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) len];
                int read = 0;
                int numRead = 0;
                while (read < fileBytes.length && (numRead = diStream.read(fileBytes, read, fileBytes.length - read)) >= 0) {
                    read = read + numRead;
                }
                fileEvent.setFileSize(len);
                fileEvent.setFileData(fileBytes);
                fileEvent.setStatus("Success");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fileEvent.setStatus("Error");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("path specified is not pointing to a file");
            fileEvent.setStatus("Error");
        }
        //Now writing the FileEvent object to socket
        try {
            outputStream.writeObject(fileEvent);
            System.out.println("Done...Going to exit");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.connect();
        client.sendFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: The code posted does not include any swing gui. What did you try ?

Comment: *"also suggest some easy codes to create a desktop application"* uver fbzrbar [<- ROT 13]